# Handler handleMessage not being called

Tags: android, handler

I am running a simple handler and even when I do a handler.sendMessage(), the handleMessage method is not called.

Here is the Handler definition:

```
protected static class TimeoutHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<PROQuestion> activity;

    public TimeoutHandler(PROQuestion activity) {
        this.activity = new WeakReference<PROQuestion>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { //never gets called
        boolean firstScreen = true;
        if (activity.get() == null) {
            removeCallbacksAndMessages(0);
        } else {
            Intent startNewActivityOpen = null;  
            startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(activity.get(), Home.class);

            startNewActivityOpen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            Bundle bundle = activity.get().getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) startNewActivityOpen.putExtras(bundle);
            activity.get().startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);

            activity.get().finish();
   }
 }
```

I am calling the handler on the main thread of my onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   TimeoutHandler handlerTimeout = new TimeoutHandler(this);

   if (handlerTimeout != null) {
        removeTimeout();
        Message message = handlerTimeout.obtainMessage();
        message.what = 100;
        handlerTimeout.sendMessage(message);
        //handlerTimeout.sendMessageAtTime(message, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + GlobalVars.longTimeout);
    }
    if (handlerTimeout.hasMessages(100)) { //returns true
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),"messages found");
    }
 }
```

Why is the handleMessage method never called?  There are no error messages or crashes.

Comment: what does  removeTimeout(); do. also did you debug with break points to see where the control goes

Comment: @Raghunandan, remove timeout removes the messages in the handler.  Is is essesentially handlerTimeout.removeMessagesAndCallbacks(0);  And yes, I have been debugging this for an hour.

Comment: comment out that line and try again.

Comment: @Raghunandan Same thing.  handleMessage is not called.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object). so remove is not necessary there. you can remove that when your activity is stopped in onStop. sendMessge should work

Comment: OK, but not sure that this will solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185959/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kristy-welsh).

Comment: Just tested, working fine